# How to get the placeholder value of a select2 dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown like this:

```
$('.to_country_dropdown').select2({
    placeholder: "Sweden",
    language: {
        noResults: function () {
            return "Vi hittar inte landet!"
        }  
    }
});
```

Then in another place I want to get this placeholder value. I have tried this:

```
$('.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder').val();
$('.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder');
```

But both that returns undefined.

Comment: if you want the value of your placeholder attribute, just use `$('.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder')`

Comment: try this `$('.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder')` .

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please see edit

Comment: @prasad Please see edit!

Comment: @vonhact Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've you need to select the placeholder value of the select you will have to select it by the class `select2-selection__placeholder'`

```js
$('.to_country_dropdown').select2({
    placeholder: "Sweden",
    language: {
        noResults: function () {
            return "Vi hittar inte landet!"
        }  
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
console.log($(".to_country_dropdown ").next().find('.select2-selection__placeholder').text())
})
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="to_country_dropdown"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.to_country_dropdown').data('select2').selection.placeholder.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other inputs with a "to_country_dropdown" class? If so, you should put an ID(unique) to each one of it. So you could do something like this

```
    $('#ID.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder')
```

Comment: This would still not solve the problem for the OP about getting the placeholder value

Comment: if you have two select  with a class named "to_country_dropdown", then you'll do $('#.to_country_dropdown').attr('placeholder'). It will return an empty string.

Comment: ronniel, yes you can do it by Id's but as i said, it still dont help with the getting the placeholder value

Comment: Oh. I get what you mean. Hmmm